# What is "pragma h" in transform-react-jsx?

Tags: reactjs, preact

I faced this configuration here https://github.com/developit/zero-to-preact/blob/master/webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
    ['transform-react-jsx', { pragma: 'h' }]
]
```

The docs says

> pragma
>
> string, defaults to React.createElement.
>
> Replace the function used when compiling JSX expressions.
>
> Note that the @jsx React.DOM pragma has been deprecated as of React v0.12

but no clue about what 'h' means! What is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, babel, etc, will transform `<div id="hello" />` to `React.createElement("div", { id: "hello" });`.  `pragma: h` will generate instead, as `h("div", { id: "hello" });`.

`React.createElement`, (or `h` for Preact) is the function to build the virtual DOM.